# Eclipse not showing all packages from git repo

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I'm working a **Maven** project that is stored on a **Google Drive folder**  Since I'm working on two different machines (**desktop** and **laptop**), I've also made **on each of them a workspace** in which I've imported the project (I know that maybe it's a bad idea to store things in cloud, but I don't know a better solution).

Now, after **working on the laptop** on some branches, deleting and creating some , **the desktop folder has trouble** in showing all the changes.

When I load the project, eclipse directly puts me on the latest branch selected (which is correct) but **the new packages are missing**. But from the **Git Window** they are there in the .git folder, just not showing in the **Package Explorer**. I've tried to **pull** from the remote repo but all I get is an "up to date".

So I've tried to **delete the .metadata** folder, importing the Maven project again and relinking the local git repo to the project, but no luck, it still misses those package.

What can I do?

Comment: Try `Project -> Clean`.

Comment: This did nothing, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!

When pulling the results, Eclipse **created new folders for the packages** on the local git repository with the new modified files, and deleted the old folders. Trouble is, that it renamed the new folders appending `(1)`, so eclipse couldn't read them. I did it by **opening the Team Synchronizing window** and renaming the folders by removing `(1)`